# Any idea on how to use gcp stackdriver to collect logs when query result of bigquery is empty (using pthon)?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a cloud function which is executing a query and storing job result into new bigquery table. I would like to store logs into stackdriver whenever I get query job result is empty, that means no record found for that particular query execution. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this task.

cloud function code:

```
def main(request):

    query = "select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`"
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_dataset = client.dataset(destination_dataset, destination_project)
    dest_table = dest_dataset.table(destination_table)
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
    job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
```

Comment: You could try using the property [`total_rows`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/query.py#L540) from the results, something like `r=job.result(); if r.total_rows == 0: stack_client.send_log()`.

Comment: @WillianFuks based on your suggestions I did some modifications in my code and it is giving me what I expected. Below is the code:

logging_client = logging.Client()
log_name = 'bigquery-logs'
logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

if r.total_rows is None:
    logger.log_text("Received empty query result")

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Stackdriver logging section in the GCP console.
- Activate advanced filter (click on the arrow on the right of the filter field)
- fill the custom field with this:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
"device_states"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.getqueryresults"
NOT protoPayload.serviceData.jobGetQueryResultsResponse.totalResults>"0"
```

By this, you select only the total result equal to 0. The tricks is that the totalResults is missing with there is 0 result. With this syntax, that works.

Then you can create an export to BigQuery, Storage or PubSub, or create a metric. If you do this, then you could use this metric in Stackdriver monitoring and alerting. All depends what do you want to do with.

Comment: I tried it by your way but in my case it is not giving me desire output. Code which I tried after filling custom fields in filter is :

logging_client = logging.Client()
log_name = 'bigquery-logs'
logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)
try:
    job.result()
    r = job.result()
    if r.total_rows == 0:
        logger.log_text("Received empty query result")
except RuntimeError:
    print(client1.report_exception())

Note= As part of testing I am using empty table in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create sink the logs in the either using code or using GCP logging UI

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

Write code in the pass the logs to bigquery

```
private static MonitoredResource monitoredResource = 
MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global")
  .addLabel("project_id", logging.getOptions().getProjectId())
  .build();

public static void writeLog(Severity severity, String logName, Map<String, String> jsonMap) {
List<Map<String, String>> maps = limitMap(jsonMap);
for (Map<String, String> map : maps) {
  LogEntry logEntry = LogEntry.newBuilder(Payload.JsonPayload.of(map))
      .setSeverity(severity)
      .setLogName(logName)
      .setResource(monitoredResource)
      .build();
  logging.write(Collections.singleton(logEntry));
}
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results